# determining if a datetime is between two other dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have multiple series of "start" and "stop" times in a set of data, and would like to see if a particular set of dates/times does or does not fall between a given set of "start/stop" times. I'm using pandas in python, and I've tried having the data as dataframes or as timeseries- haven't gotten either to work. I've been using this bit of code:

```
 print (start1 < test1[0:LenS] < stop1).any()
```

(note that the "test1[0:LenS]" is just to make sure test1 is the same length as start1 and stop1) and I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Since I'm trying to use .any(), I'm pretty confused. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot combine Series comparison like that.

```
(start1 < test1[0:LenS]) & (test1[0:LenS]<stop)
```

should work to test multiple conditions at once.

Comment: That did the trick. Follow-up question: I can get the code to tell me whether or not a value in "test1" falls in the time range....how do I figure out which value/values in "test1" made the statement true, and/or what their index number is?

Comment: In this case, I would try to be working with a Dataframe : Dataframe are tables that contain one series per column.  In this framework you can lightly compute all 4 columns side by side to be able to visualize more easily

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `pandas.Series.between` as

```
test1[0:LenS].between(start1, stop1).any()
```

Comment: Wasn't able to get it to work...too bad, this seems pretty simple/elegant.